# CASE statement with select clause causing an error in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Just wanted to get `cdcid` associated with multiple `organizationId` and put a flag Y for the same and N else.

I used this query:

```
WITH ts AS
(
    SELECT  
        COUNT(*), cdcid, organizationId  
    FROM 
        new_user_association  
    GROUP BY 
        cdcid, organizationId  
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.cdcId AS cdc_ID, a.organizationId AS organization_Id,  
    emailAddress AS user_email_ID, current_timestamp AS rec_crt_ts,  
    current_timestamp AS rec_updt_ts,  
    CASE 
        WHEN a.cdcId = ts.cdcid 
            THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' 
    END AS user_active_in_multiple_orgs_flag  
FROM
    new_user_association a, ts
```

And I got a result like this:

```
cdc_id                            | organization_Id  |user_active_in_multiple_orgs_flag

0a157cd10353472a8a61773963e50ede  |1000078593        |N
0a157cd10353472a8a61773963e50ede  |1000079079        |Y
```

I then tried to use a `select` statement in the `case` as shown here:

```
CASE 
    WHEN cdcid IN (SELECT DISTINCT cdcid FROM ts) 
        THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N' 
END AS user_active_in_multiple_orgs_flag
```

But I get this error:

> AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join and a few commands

What is the right approach to fix this?

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Your case expression is valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: Using below is not working as well:
select distinct(cdcid) from (
SELECT  COUNT(*),cdcid 
,organizationId
FROM new_user_association
GROUP BY cdcid 
,organizationId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) tm

Comment: I'm using spark sql

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Add your problem SQL as an edit to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, you can have a [left join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html) with ts and [group by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html) clause on top of your existing query to get the result you want.

Here is the query:

```
WITH ts AS
(
    SELECT  
        COUNT(*), cdcid, organizationId  
    FROM 
        new_user_association  
    GROUP BY 
        cdcid, organizationId  
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
    a.cdcId AS cdc_ID, 
    a.organizationId AS organization_Id,  
    emailAddress AS user_email_ID, 
    MAX(current_timestamp) AS rec_crt_ts,  
    MAX(current_timestamp) AS rec_updt_ts,
    COUNT(ts.cdcid) > 0 AS user_active_in_multiple_orgs_flag  
FROM
    new_user_association a
LEFT JOIN    
    ts
ON
    a.cdcid = ts.cdcid
GROUP BY 
    a.cdcId,
    a.organizationId,
    emailAddress
```